# Multiple conditional probabilities

Tags: conditional-probability

Is it possible to calculate an expression $P(C_1,C_2,C_3|L_1,L_2,L_3)$ if I know only the individual $P(C_x)$ and all combinations of $P(C_x|L_y)$? How would I do that? Thanks!

Comment: You need to know something about which events are independent of each other, too.

Comment: Does your notation mean "probability of $C_1$ **and** $C_2$" or "probability of $C_1$ **or** $C_2$" (same for the conditions)?

Comment: @mjqxxxx Yes, the $L's$ are independent. And the $C's$ are dependent on the outcome of the $L's$.

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud Sorry, I can see that my notation here looks creative. I mean **and**.

Comment: I would really appreciate any help on this. @mjqxxxx ?